# missing one required positional argument

Tags: python, blockchain, hashlib

I was working on a blockchain project. Nothing wrong seemed to come of it, until I added the mining function. Then it spit out two errors that it was missing positional argument. the first was the main function on line 45, and the second one was that if name is main function. which makes since. It had to do with the mining function. The code is a bit lengthy and hard to understand so I am keeping the necessary parts.

```
from hashlib import sha3_512

##some hashing stuff
class Block():
## the variables thrown into the function
    def __init__(self, txdata, number):
         #initialize function.
    # More hashing stuff
class blockchain:
    difficulty = 4
    def __init__(self, chain=[]):
        #Initialize function. Sets up the blockchain
    def add(self,Block):
        #lables adding stuff to the chain
    def mine(self,Block):
        try:
            block.prev = self.chain[-1].get('hash')
        except IndexError:
            pass
        while True:
            if Block.hash()[:blockchain.difficulty] == "0"*blockchain.difficulty:
                self.add(Block)
                break
            else:
                Block.nonce +=1
def main():
    blockchain()
    bchain = ["Nice day stack overflow", "Once again I need help with my bad code"]
    Num = 0
    for txdata in bchain:
        Num += 1
        blockchain.mine(Block(Block.txdata, Num)) #the error popped up here. I don't get it. I tried fiddling around with it, nothing.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can you help me solve this error. It could ruin the entire project if not fixed.
Error

```
Traceback(most recent call last)
 File "blockchain.py", line 47 in <module>
   main()
 File "blockchain.py", line 45, in main()
   blockchain.mine(Block(Block.txdata, Num))
Type error: mine missing one positional argument: Block
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep hold of the instance of `blockchain()`.

```py
def main():
    b = blockchain()  # keep hold of the instance in b
    bchain = ["Nice day stack overflow", "Once again I need help with my bad code"]
    Num = 0
    for txdata in bchain:
        Num += 1
        b.mine(Block(Block.txdata, Num))   # Use the instance here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I don't know how changing it to a variable helped. But thank you. My code now runs without spewing errors out